# Hangfire job enqueued using interface ignores specified job filters on class/method level

Tags: hangfire

Consider we have the following class:

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 3)]
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    [ErrorReporting(Attempts = 1)]
    public async Task Send()
    {
    }
}

public interface IEmailSender
{
    Task Send();
}
```

And we enqueue job in this way:

```
backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IEmailSender>(s => s.Send());
```

Just to mention, I use SimpleInjector and it's Hangfire job activator.

First of all `Attempts` property from `AutomaticRetry` attribute is not taken into account. When it comes to `ErrorReporting` custom attribute it is not executed at all.

Seems Hangfire checks defined attributes just on registered type (interface in my case) not the instance type that will be resolved.

In my case `IEmailSender` is defined in seperate project. I believe one solution would be to keep it together with `EmailSender` and custom attributes implementation, plus define attributes on interface level but I wouldn't like to do it in this way since my Hangfire jobs are processed in Windows Service and jobs themselves are enqueued by clients (using interfaces) so there is no need for clients to know anything about implementation.

Do you have any idea how I could solve this issue in a good way? Can we somehow configure those filters when creating `BackgroundJobServer` in Windows Service?

Comment: This is very important information for anyone using those attributes. It explains why our attributes always seemed to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in this way:
https://gist.github.com/rwasik/80f1dc1b7bbb8b8a9b47192f0dfd4664

If you have any other ideas please let me know.